# Can an Indian national in F1 and B1/B2 visa travel to Mexico?

Tags: indian-citizens, b1-b2-visas, mexico, f1-visas

Can an Indian national travel to Mexico in F1 visa?I also have an B1/B2 visa but I am residing in US currently in F1 status.
And what about people with H1B visas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Mexican consulate in San Francisco says that you do not need a visa as long as you have valid and unexpired USA visa (or permanent residence).

> Other nationalities, Non-US Permanent Residents. Starting May 1st,
>   2010, all those foreign nationals, regardless of their nationality,
>   visiting Mexico for tourist, business or transit matters won't need a
>   Mexican visa as long as they have with them a valid and not expired
>   USA visa in the passport. In this context, if you have a valid US visa
>   in the passport you do not need to obtain a Mexican visa.

The website is [here](http://consulmex.sre.gob.mx/sanfrancisco/index.php/visas-traveling-to-mexico).

Similar, but more clearly stated information is available on the Consulate of Mexico in India [website](http://embamex.sre.gob.mx/india/index.php/en/consular-section/visas) which says:

> :: NOTICE FOR HOLDERS OF USA VISA ::
>
> Holders of any valid visa for the United States of America (any nationality) DO NOT require visa to enter Mexico on tourist, business
>   and transit purposes only.

Comment: @pnuts yes, very! incorporated into answer.